# F-Strings and writing function output to file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, function, file-writing

I want to simply write output of my function to a file, but it returns None. The function itself works perfectly fine and just print statements.

```
#I have reproduced the issue with minimum LOC:
def syl(txt):
    for x in text:
        print(x)

text = 'example text'
file = 'example'

with open(F"""SYL_{file}""",'a+',encoding='UTF8') as f:
   f.write(F'''{syl(text)}''')
   content = f.readlines()
   print(content)
```

## Prints '[]'

```
F'''{syl(text)}'''" #it returns only 'None'.
```

I have tried also:

```
with open(F"""SYL_{file}""",'a+',encoding='UTF8') as f:
   f.write(syl(text)) #str(syl(text)) Doesnt work too, writelines() also changes nothing.
```

Comment: The f-string use seems fine to me, it's just that `syl` doesn't return anything, and `readlines()` after `write()` is pointless (do a `f.seek(0)` before!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the function actually *returns* something (a function with no explicit returns, returns `None`), print statements simply appear on the console and don't get processed as the output of the function. Try this, using a list comprehension:

```
def syl(txt):
    # returns a list of the chars in txt
    return [x for x in txt]
```

Now for the writing part. Well, it turns out that you don't actually need to call the function (what did you intend to do with the function?), just write the text:

```
f.write(text)
```